# How to compile h5py to deal with a precompiled mpi4py package?

Tags: mpi, hdf5, h5py, paraview, mpi4py

I am trying to compile [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/) to run with the [mpi4py](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that comes already compiled with [ParaView](https://www.paraview.org/). As soon as I try to import the *h5py* package I get the error message:

```
ValueError: mpi4py.MPI.Status has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 40, got 48
```

I am using [Open MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/) to build h5py with the *--mpi* option to make use of the parallel functionalities.

I am suspecting the issue being how I compiled *Open MPI* but I could not find a flag in the *configure* script that looks something like the error message.

Any help/link/comment is appreciated.

Comment: did you built `mpi4py` on top of the `Open MPI` you built ?

Comment: Do you use an identical build environment there? (same Python, NumPy, OpenMPI, etc. as used for ParaView?)